# Yii2 Require Login with Error Handling not working

Tags: php, yii2

I have the folowing snippet that i use to force login with yii2 projects

```
$config = [
'id' => 'basic',

'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),

'on beforeAction' => function ($event){

    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl))
    {
        Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl));
    }
},
```

This seems to work for the vast majority of situations. However, if I try to access a controller/action/url that does not exist I get the 404 page as expected. The issue I am having is that if someone is a guest I do not even want them to see the error page, plain and simple they can log in or they can view the login page. With the above snippet the redirect does not seem to work and the error page is shown.

Has anyone come across a similar issue or a solution for this?

**Update**

I have tested placing a redirect on the error page itself ie

```
<?php
return Yii::$app->controller->redirect("http://www.google.com");
?>
```

It seems even this redirect is not working. So it is as though redirect will simply never work when an error exists.

Answer (score 0):

Once again the documentation for yii is king. Even though I had scanned the Error Handler Docs about 10 times there was one piece of information I clearly missed.

In the [Error Handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html#using-error-actions) docs we can see the following line:

> Note: If you need to redirect in an error handler, do it the following way: `php Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect($url)->send(); return;`

So if I change my snippet to the following everything is right in the world again.

```
'on beforeAction' => function ($event){

    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest && Yii::$app->getRequest()->url !== Url::to(Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl))
    {
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Url::to(\Yii::$app->getUser()->loginUrl))->send(); 
        return;
    }

},
```

Think I'll be updating my snippets now.